# Being able to see deleted answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've seen in the past questions on the meta dealing with case specific problems that have been very intriguing, yet to find out that the linked question had been deleted resulting in the "Page not found!" prompt.

After one of these questions are raised to view, they are usually deleted soon thereafter, leaving the Meta-post as a blob of text, with little reference to the post, which doesn't seem all that great. I don't want to ramble so I'll keep this brief.

I think there should either be a cache of the question saved when deleted so that it can be referenced, or **some way** to view said questions (see below.) Thoughts?

> ***EDIT:*** 
>   As pointed out by @Serg when reaching 10,000 reputation or more, you can view deleted answers, however I feel it would be good for new users to see these ridiculous mistakes being called out, so that they would know what not to do when it came to asking a question.

Comment: Users over 10k reputation can view deleted posts. Maybe having a sort of image gallery with screenshots of each post would be useful. Just a thought

Comment: @Serg Yes, very good idea. Another good question would be why you need 10k reputation to view a question, it might be good for new users to be able to see what not to do when asking a question,

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice Why not make a meta compilation of bad questions? You could find them and screenshot them before they are removed. The reason it is a 10k privilege to see deleted answers, is so those users can user the other privileges to asses if the question should be reopened. The problem is, if everyone can see deleted posts, then what is the point of removing them?

Comment: The point would be removing them from the feed, to clear up space for those questions that do actually matter, perhaps maybe only be able to see deleted questions when you link it directy @MarkKirby

Comment: Well, I can't really argue with that. IDK if SE will ever lower that limit but I do see where seeing some deleted questions, could have value for some, perhaps not new 1 rep users but 1k to 5k sure. One way you can find bad questions is through the `votes` filter and then go to the last page, these are the most downvoted questions on the site, some could learn form these, I like to read them and find funny ones http://askubuntu.com/questions?page=4780&sort=votes

Comment: Always fun :) @MarkKirby